# send touch drag to a GameObject using TouchScript on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, drag, multi-touch

I'm doing a Standalone Windows 7 unity3d application for use on a multitouch IR Frame. 
I usually use TouchScript and no problem with this. But now I don't know how to solve a new problem.

I have a texture with a uWebKit web and I need to send to this GameObject the touch drag to move a map and make zoom.

I can send touch Down and Up but I don't know how to pass the move.

It's ok for me to use other solution than TouchScript if go well.

Thanks you.